# WinForms:EnableVisualStyles() doesn't work if a USING statement is in program.cs?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-styles

So in my program.cs file, this default code works perfectly:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault (false);
Application.Run (new frmClarity());
```

However, if I try to add a using statement, EnableVisualStyles() doesn't seem to execute anymore!  No errors, it just doesn't style the forms.  Both of these attempts have the effect of visual styles not executing:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault (false);

    using (new Impersonator.Impersonator (
    
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["login"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["domain"], 
       ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["password"])) {
    
       Application.Run (new frmClarity());
    }
}
```

OR

```
using (new Impersonator.Impersonator (

   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["login"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["domain"], 
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ["password"])) {

   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault (false);

   Application.Run (new frmClarity());
}
}
```

Does anyone know why adding a USING statement in program.cs causes this weird behavior?

Comment: It must execute before *any* windows are created.  We can't see what Impersonator does, the syntax error doesn't exactly help.  There is no good reason to delay it.

Comment: No windows are created by Impersonator.  It just changes the account that the app is running under.  Sorry for the syntax error--I put the extra brace in above. There are no syntax errors in my executing code).  In my first "not working" example, EnableVisualStyles() is the very first thing that executes.